# How to switch focus (becomeFirstResponder) between textfields in different parent views

Tags: ios, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I have 3 custom objects which each contains 3 uitextfields.

when I press next in the keyboard I am able to pass focus to the next UITextFiled though textFieldShouldReturn and becomeFirstResponder. this is fine while they reside in the same parent view. But how can I pass focus to an UITextFiled in a different parent view?

[image: Rows are different Views]

Each row represents a different view. So my problem is passing focus from text3 to text4.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `becomeFirstResponder` on "text4". So, depending on how you have this all setup (I'll assume they're just `IBOutlets`) you'll want to do something along the lines of this:

```
- (IBAction) userHitReturnOnTextField:(UITextField *)sender {
     if (sender == self.text1) [self.text2 becomeFirstResponder];
     else if (sender == self.text2) [self.text3 becomeFirstResponder];
     ...
     else [self.view endEditing:YES]; // hides the keyboard
}
```

Of course you can get more creative and store your `UITextFields` in an array and your logic will get simpler depending on the number of textfields you have:

```
- (IBAction) userHitReturnOnTextField:(UITextField *)sender {
     int nextIndex = [self.myArrayOfTextFields indexOfObject:sender] + 1;
     if (nextIndex < self.myArrayOfTextFields.count) {
         UITextField *nextField = self.myArrayOfTextFields[nextIndex];
         [nextField becomeFirstResponder];
     } else [self.view endEditing:YES]; // hides the keyboard
}
```

Comment: That would work if they al resided on ONE container, but I am trying to call becomeFirstResponder from one container to a different one... Assume that they are 3 objects and each object has 3 textfields. - userHitReturn OnTextField is called from object 1, but it cannot see object 2 since it resides on the paren container.

Comment: @BenQuan Then you'll have to pass them around and store them in one place using `-prepareForSegue:`